# Xamarin.Forms load API data and Azure data into Device

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I would like my app to download API and Azure data at start.
The data would be stored in the device and used as needed by my App.
What would be the best approach to this?

Q1: Should I download the data into:
 
A) local database in the device (SQLite database, SQL Server Compact)?
 
B) local file system (PCLStorage nuget)?
 
C) object in memory for the lifetime of my application?

Q2: how do real life programmer pros manage storing (or caching) data in enterprise mobile applications?

======================== UPDATE ==============================

I'm not sure I constructed my questions clearly enough, so let me rephrase:

**I will use Azure, and I would like my app to be able to:

1. donload pictures (and other data) at startup, while splash screen is showing.

2. cash data in order to work offline

3. update and cash again fresh data

4. have push notifications**

1. What would be the best approach?
2. What is a good combo to use with azure to store the data locally (in the device)? Is it necessary to use SQLite or is there a better way?
3. Is it SQLite that enterprise apps use in such cases?

Comment: it really depends on the specific use case and the nature of the data, but generally you would use a SQLite db on the client to store any local data

Comment: @Jason just to be specific your advice would be to use SQLite DB. Deserialize your comment into an answer object please, so I can accept it if it turns out to be the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: What API and Azure data are you dealing with, and what is the structure of your data?

Comment: @BruceChen I don't know what you mean by "structure of data", however I can tell you this: I have multiple <ListView>s that display people and I need to download their photos (*.png) from a database and "pre-load" the PeopleListPage so that it contains the appropriate images and so that it loads quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without diving to far down the rabbit hole some version of all 3 could be used in the same app depending on the type of data you are storing,

Real life example:

1. Enterprise localization/branding data(strings, images) Ive stored a in a SQL lite database so it wouldn't require a new compile for every change it could be updated via a web service so every change doesn't need to be pushed through the apple process.
2. Local file for cross platform user settings simple JSON file of basic settings
3. Current session data is stored in memory for a variety of client reasons it could never be written to local storage